# Privilege type text is swapped

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

The text for 'Privilege type' is swapped on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

It read: `Milestone privilegePrivilege type:`, but it should be `Privilege type: Milestone` privilege

Comment: To be as inclusive as possible SE changes its grammar into [Yoda style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346184/backwards-the-migration-close-reason-text-is). Expect this to be [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: Language is complicated and don't always follow rules that make completely sense, programmers taht try to get it in to code like gettext  can sing you a song for it. You can program all into it, but it takes time and lots of testing ti get it right and there a lot of other problem that mus be address first i hope. Besides rome wasn't build i a day or two

Comment: You mean "Is swapped privilege type text", right?